# changing the option text in a flip toggle switch in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a toggle switch component in jQuery Mobile ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aD5xD/3/))

```
<select name="toggle" id="toggle" data-role="slider">
    <option id="value1" value="off">value1</option>
    <option id="value2" value="on">value2</option>
</select>
```

I want to be able to change the displayed text programmatically at any given moment.

e.g. "value1" should become "newvalue1" and "value2" should become "newvalue2".

This function should re-create the toggle-switch with the new values, but actually it does nothing:

```
function yourfunction() { 
    //alert ("Changing stuff");
    $('#value1').html ('newvalue1');
    $('#value2').html ('newvalue2');
    var myswitch = $("#toggle");
    myswitch.slider("refresh", true);
}
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 3000);​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

- http://jsfiddle.net/aD5xD/13/

JS

```
function yourfunction() { 
        //alert ("Changing stuff");
        $('.ui-slider-label-a').text('newvalue1');
        $('.ui-slider-label-b').text('newvalue2');
        var myswitch = $("#toggle");
        myswitch.slider("refresh", true);

    }
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 3000);​
```

jQM Adds a class for both options ( `ui-slider-label-a` and `ui-slider-label-b` ), by using these classes you can access the correct element and change the text.

NOTE: The best way to see the additional markup jQM adds is to use Google Chrome ( IMHO ) and inspect the element

Comment: This works. I don't like changing all the class instances, but selecting inside the outside div seems to do the trick.


`<div class="containing-element" id="bigSwitch">` and `$('#bigSwitch .ui-slider-label-a').text('newvalue1');`

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#value1').text('newvalue1');` instead of `$('#value1').html('newvalue1');`

Comment: in that case, your text modification is working, but the slider is not refreshing properly, try putting  myswitch.selectmenu(); before 
    myswitch.selectmenu(refresh, true);

Comment: er, do you mean myswitch.slider() before myswitch.slider("refresh", true); ?

Comment: arent they effectively the same? a slider is a <select> with fancy styling... it shouldnt matter which one you use

Comment: myswitch.selectmenu();
myswitch.selectmenu(refresh, true);
creates a new drop-down menu on the page

myswitch.slider();
myswitch.slider("refresh", true);
does nothing.